# JS Как сделать фильтрацию в таблице с учетом фильтра в другом столбце?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы фильтрация в таблице работала с учетом выбранного фильтра в другом столбце?

```js
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  input = document.getElementsByClassName(target.className)[0];
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  console.log(filter);
  if (target.tagName == "INPUT") {
    let num = +target.className;

    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[num];
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Расположите значок поиска */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Не повторяйте изображение значка */
  width: 30%;
  /* Полная ширина */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Увеличить размер шрифта */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Добавить немного отступов */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Добавить серую границу */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Добавить некоторое пространство под входом */
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Свернуть границы */
  width: 100%;
  /* Полная ширина */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Добавить серую границу */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Увеличить размер шрифта */
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* Выравнивание текста по левому краю */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Добавить отступ */
}

#myTable tr {
  /* Добавить нижнюю границу для всех строк таблицы */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  /* Добавить серый цвет фона для заголовка таблицы и при наведении курсора мыши */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>


  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:40%;">Имя: <input type="text" id="myInput" class="0" placeholder="Поиск имен.."></th>
      <th style="width:30%;">Страна: <input type="text" id="myInput" class="1" placeholder="Поиск имен.."></th>
      <th style="width:30%;">Статус: <input type="text" id="myInput" class="2" placeholder="Поиск имен.."></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Германия</td>
      <td>Город</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Швеция</td>
      <td>Столица</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Великобритания</td>
      <td>Столица</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>Германия</td>
      <td>Гоорд</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что-то намудрили Вы и с разметкой и со стилями и со скриптом. Копипастить надо вдумчиво :-) В общем, я вижу решение так (не слишком лаконично, но просто и понятно) :

```js
table = document.getElementById('myTable');
// Делегирование обработчика для полей ввода
table.addEventListener('input', fResultFilter);
// Назначение обработчиков для кнопок очистки
[...table.querySelectorAll('.header input + span')].forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.target.previousElementSibling.value = '';
    ev.target.previousElementSibling.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
  });
});

function fResultFilter(ev) {
  // Скрытие/показ кнопок очистки
  ev.target.nextElementSibling.style.transform = (ev.target.value != '') ? 'scaleX(1)' : '';
  // Получаем все строки, кроме заголовка
  let aTRs = [...table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)')];
  // Получаем значения всех полей поиска
  let aSearch = [...table.querySelectorAll('th > input')];
  // Прогоняем строки через цепочку фильтров
  aTRs.filter(function(el) {
    if (el.children[0].textContent.search(new RegExp(`${aSearch[0].value}`, 'i')) < 0) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }).filter(function(el) {
    if (el.children[1].textContent.search(new RegExp(`${aSearch[1].value}`, 'i')) < 0) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }).filter(function(el) {
    if (el.children[2].textContent.search(new RegExp(`${aSearch[2].value}`, 'i')) < 0) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      return false;
    } else {
      // Показываем только нужные строки
      el.style.display = '';
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.header input {
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Расположите значок поиска */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Не повторяйте изображение значка */
  width: 100%;
  /* Полная ширина */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Увеличить размер шрифта */
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  /* Добавить немного отступов */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Добавить серую границу */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header input+span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 23%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 19px;
  width: 19px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(33, 110, 243, 0.44);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform .4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Свернуть границы */
  width: 100%;
  /* Полная ширина */
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  /* Добавить серую границу */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Увеличить размер шрифта */
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* Выравнивание текста по левому краю */
  padding: 10px;
  /* Добавить отступ */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#myTable th {
  position: relative;
}

#myTable tr {
  /* Добавить нижнюю границу для всех строк таблицы */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  /* Добавить серый цвет фона для заголовка таблицы и при наведении курсора мыши */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Имя: <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск..."><span>×</span></th>
    <th>Страна: <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск..."><span>×</span></th>
    <th>Статус: <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск..."><span>×</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Германия</td>
    <td>Город</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Швеция</td>
    <td>Столица</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Великобритания</td>
    <td>Столица</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Германия</td>
    <td>Гоорд</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: бездумно, я конечно не копипастил. Да взял готовое решение и сделал по себя.
В вашем решении, впервые столкнулся с конструкцией 
let aTRs = [...table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)')]
Что это означает?

Comment: @SemenDorofeev: преобразование коллекции в массив, с помощью недавно введённого оператора `...` Про него можно почитать [здесь](http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-spread-rest)