# Поиск совпадения текста в html элементах jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу скрыть элементы `div` содержимое которых не совпадает содержимому `input`.
Если содержимое `div="Один"` а содержимое `input="од"` то `div` не скрывается.

Попытка:

```js
$("#search_text").keyup(function(e) {
  var text = $("#search_text").val();
  if ($(".search_block div").text() != text) {
    $(this).hide;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search_text">
<div class="search_block">
  <div>Один</div>
  <div>Два</div>
  <div>Три</div>
  <div>Четыре</div>
  <div>Пять</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".search_block div")` - возвращает коллекцию элементов. Надо сделать по ней цикл. А почему прячете инпут `$(this).hide;`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko можете продемонстрировать код?

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин: возможно, что Вас заинтересует и вопрос и ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1092067/265406

Comment: @UModeL спасибо, но думаю можно проще сделать.

Comment: А как добавить надпись "Нет совпадений" если ничего не выдало по поиску?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коротко и понятно. Макияж по своему усмотрению:

```js
$("#search_text").on('input', function() {
  let text = $("#search_text").val();
  $(".search_block > div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(`${text}`, 'i')) < 0 && text != '') {
      $(this).hide("slow");
    } else {
      $(this).show("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search_text">
<div class="search_block">
  <div>Один</div>
  <div>Два</div>
  <div>Три</div>
  <div>Четыре</div>
  <div>Пять</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Не очень это хорошо - искать по regexp. Как искать по спецсимволам? Например, при вводе `[` - работать не будет совсем.

Comment: В первую очередь, проблемы не надо создавать на пустом месте :) А вы свои рабочие проекты тоже по такому принципу пишите? Есть мокап, в нем *lorem ipsum*, о там не будет никаких символов, сделаю я regexp. А когда появятся баги - буду их править :) Хотя можно обойтись `indexOf`, который еще и быстрее будет.

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по regexp лучше не использовать в данной задачи, т.к. будут проблемы со спец символами, например `() . [] *` и т.д.

Можно, конечно, их экранировать, но это лишняя работа, которая не принесет пользы.

Попробуйте поискать по символу `[` в данном примере.

```js
$("#search_text").on('input', function() {
  let text = $("#search_text").val();
  $(".search_block > div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(`${text}`, 'i')) < 0 && text != '') {
      $(this).hide("slow");
    } else {
      $(this).show("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search_text">
<div class="search_block">
  <div>Один</div>
  <div>Два</div>
  <div>Три</div>
  <div>Четыре</div>
  <div>Пять</div>
  <div>Шесть[]</div>
</div>
```

Поиск лучше сделать через `indexOf`.

Он работает быстрее и для данной задачи вполне достаточен.

```js
$("#search_text").on('input', function() {
  let text = $("#search_text").val().toLowerCase();
  $(".search_block > div").each(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) === -1) {
      $this.hide("slow");
    } else {
      $this.show("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search_text">
<div class="search_block">
  <div>Один</div>
  <div>Два</div>
  <div>Три</div>
  <div>Четыре</div>
  <div>Пять</div>
  <div>Шесть[]</div>
</div>
```

И напоследок, небольшое сравнение производительности `Regexp` и `indexOf`.

```js
const array = new Array(1000000).fill(1)

console.time('regexp');
const searchRegexp = new RegExp(`${'1'}`, 'i');
array.forEach(f => {
  const result = ('hello' + f).search(searchRegexp);
});
console.timeEnd('regexp');


console.time('indexof');
const searchStr = '1';
array.forEach(f => {
  const result = ('hello' + f).toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr) === -1;
});
console.timeEnd('indexof');
```

Comment: Вот. Сами надумали проблему - сами её решили. Вы - молодец! Плюсую.

Comment: @UModeL Вы думаете, что невозможность поиска по спец символам (которых довольно много и не все они совсем уже специальные) - это не проблема и не баг?

Comment: будьте благоразумны. Я больше одного плюса всё равно не могу поставить.

Comment: @UModeL при чем тут плюс. Я хочу узнать ваше мнение, поэтому задаю вопросы :)