# Как изменять (фильтровать) второй/третий список в зависимости от выбора в первом/втором?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Другом вопросе дант [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791560/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/1126105?noredirect=1#comment1946664_1126105) на вариант показа по мере выбора.

```
Страна:
<select id="country_id" class="StyleSelectBox">
  <option value="0">- выберите страну -</option>
  <option value="1">Россия</option>
  <option value="2">Украина</option>
  <option value="3">Белорусь</option>
</select>
Регион: 
<select id="region_id" disabled>
  <option value="0">- Выберите регион -</option>
</select>
Город: 
<select id="city_id" disabled>
  <option value="0">- Выберите город -</option>
</select>
<script>
    var all_regions=[];
    var all_cites=[[],[],[]];

    all_regions[0]=["московская обл","ростовская обл","саратовская обл"];
    all_regions[1]=["киевская обл","львовская обл","харьковская обл"];
    all_regions[2]=["минская обл","брестская обл","гроднинская обл"];

    all_cites[0][0]=["Москва","Химки","Калуга"];
    all_cites[0][1]=["Такой-то город","Такой-то город","Калуга"];
    all_cites[0][2]=["Такой-то город","Такой-то город","Такой-то город"];

    all_cites[1][0]=["Киев","Жмеринка","Бердычев"];
    all_cites[1][1]=["Львов","Сокаль","Стрый"];
    all_cites[1][2]=["Харьков","Полтава","Пирятин"];

    all_cites[2][0]=["Минск","Такой-то город","Такой-то город"];
    all_cites[2][1]=["Брест","Такой-то город","Такой-то город"];
    all_cites[2][2]=["Гродно","Такой-то город","Вильно"];

    country_id.onchange = function() {
        region_id.disabled = false;
        region_id.innerHTML = "<option value='0'>- Выберите регион -</option>";
        myregion = this.value - 1;
        if (myregion != -1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < all_regions[myregion].length; i++) {
                region_id.innerHTML += '<option value="' + (i+1) + '">' + all_regions[myregion][i] + '</option>';
            }
        } else {
            region_id.disabled = true;
            city_id.disabled = true;
        }
    }

    region_id.onchange = function() {
        city_id.disabled = false;
        city_id.innerHTML = "<option value='0'>- Выберите город -</option>";
        var mycite = this.value - 1;
        if (mycite != -1) {
             for (var i = 0; i < all_cites[myregion][mycite].length; i++){
                 city_id.innerHTML += '<option value="' + (i + 1) + '">' + all_cites[myregion][mycite][i] + '</option>';
             }
        } else {
            city_id.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

А как сделать чтобы все списки изначально были видны (с полосой прокрутки) и можно было обращаться напрямую - сразу нажимаешь, например московская область и отфильтровывается третий список или нажимаешь Россия и отфильтровываются все области и города из России, которые доступны для прямого обращения.
Соответственно во всех списках есть опция "ВСЕ" при выборе которой в зависимых списках отображаются все элементы.
Из примера выше при выборе "ВСЕ" из областей отображаются все города но для выбранной страны (если была выбрана!)
А при выборе "ВСЕ" из стран отображаются и все области и все города.
Спасибо

Comment: Как бы вы сами это сделали?

Comment: знал бы не спрашивал))

Comment: @selftripsru: сделайте по аналогии - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1092067/265406

Comment: Есть некоторые правила. Хорошего тона, что ли:
1. Опишите проблему кратко
2. Опишите, что вы пробовали
3. При необходимости добавьте немного кода

У вас с пунктами 1,2 не ладится. То, что вы спрашиваете, не является проблемой. Вы сами не пробовали ее решить. Да и 3 пункт просто с другого ответа скопировали. В чем смысл задавать вопрос, за который вы даже браться не хотите?

Comment: @UModeL мне надо не с таблицей а со списком выбора. (Мне надо потом выбранное значение в форму передать)
А тамлица вообще как-то не понятно если есть 10 позицей в первом столбце, 100 во 2м и 1000 в 3м....

Comment: @UModeL так как заменить на селект?